# Convert a KerasTensor object to a numpy array to visualize predictions in Callback

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am writing a custom on_train_end callback function for model.fit() method of tensorflow keras sequential model. The callback function is about plotting the predictions that the model makes, so it involves converting the inputs of the model to a numpy array and feeds it into model.predict(). I use self.model.inputs to access the inputs, which is a list of KerasTensor objects and the one at 0th index is what I want. I tried the following approach

```
class my_visualizer(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):

        x = tf.keras.backend.eval(self.model.inputs[0])
        y_predictions = self.model.predict(x)
```

but got the error

```
AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

So this method is for another type of tensor rather than KerasTensor. Other solutions I found work for tensorflow's Tensor object but not keras' KerasTensor object, and I did not find any mentioning of the ways to achieve the desired feature in keras documentation. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't exactly use `KerasTensor` objects, what worked for me on Tensorflow 2.x is passing real data to the `Callback`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def legend_without_duplicate_labels(ax):
    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    unique = [(h, l) for i, (h, l) in enumerate(zip(handles, labels)) if l not in labels[:i]]
    ax.legend(*zip(*unique))

class Visualizer(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
   def __init__(self, ds):
        self.ds = ds
   def on_train_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        features, true_labels = next(iter(self.ds.take(1)))
        ynew = self.model.predict(features)
        labels = [1 if y > 0.5 else 0 for y in tf.squeeze(ynew)]
        true_labels = [y.numpy() for y in tf.squeeze(true_labels)]
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
        fig.set_figheight(10)
        fig.set_figwidth(10)
        cdict = {0: 'red', 1: 'blue'}
        titles = ['True Labels', 'Predicted Labels']
        for ax, ls, t in zip(axes.flatten(), [true_labels, labels], titles):
          for i, txt in enumerate(ls):
            ax.scatter(features[i, 0], features[i, 1], c = cdict[txt], marker="o", label = txt, s = 100)
          legend_without_duplicate_labels(ax)
          ax.title.set_text(t)
        plt.show()

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((2,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(inputs)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy())

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.random.normal((50, 2)), tf.random.uniform((50, 1), maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32))).batch(10)
test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.random.normal((50, 2)), tf.random.uniform((50, 1), maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32))).batch(50)
model.fit(train_ds, epochs=10, callbacks=[Visualizer(test_ds)])
```

```
Epoch 1/10
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.7521
Epoch 2/10
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7433
Epoch 3/10
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7363
Epoch 4/10
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7299
Epoch 5/10
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7239
Epoch 6/10
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7183
Epoch 7/10
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7131
Epoch 8/10
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7082
Epoch 9/10
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7037
Epoch 10/10
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6994
```

[image]